# How to generate .csv file in SQL Server 2008R2 for data of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-csv

I have my database and tables with data.

I have created tables on server but now I want to import data on server so how to generate .csv file for that.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please clarify. Do you want to generate csv files that you can import to your sql server? Where are the data that you want to generate your csv files from?

Comment: Actually i have created database and tables on localhost...but now i have copy the database on server and i want to import my data into database which is on server for that i need to create csv file

Comment: When I do something like this .csv files isn't my first choice for data transfer. What more precisely is it you want to copy? Is it a thousand tables that contain millions of rows or is it just a few tables containing some default data? If it isn't too much data it may be an easy solution to generate insert scripts that you may run on the db server. The hardest part tends to be to copy keys and relationships. If the servers may connect to each other using the copy database wizard in management studio is often a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import and export wizard of the sql server is your answer, better answer is to make a backup of you localhost database and restore it on server database, fire some script to transfer the data from the restored database to your server database. Drop the restored database.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

From my understanding; you want to migrate data created on one server to another.  To do this simply, use the export wizard that comes with Sql Server.  See the following article that walks you through this process - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx